# When does local variable of class annotated with @Component goes out of memory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, class

If I have a class annotated with @Component in spring boot application, and various threads are running on application and all are accessing on local variable of @Component class, will it be same variable or every thread will make it's own copy?
How does @Component annotation really works and when does the local variable become empty?
Let's say I have `Set<String>` in class, when will this set become empty?

```
@Component 
class testing {
  Set<String> localSet;
  Set<String> getString(){ return localSet;}
}
```

If I insert some random data in localSet, when will the data be deleted here?

Comment: Spring's default scope is singleton so yes, the localSet will contain for every thread the same data. Note that all code needs to be thread-safe. Generally it's not a good idea to keep state in a singleton scoped bean.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: It's never a good idea to start programming with a framework for which you don't even understand the basics. May I suggest you start by reading an article, book or documentation first before asking these very basic questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are wondering about the "scope" of `@Component` as you mention that different threads will be accessing the same resource (In your case your classes' variables)

The default scope of `@Component` is singleton which as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) in the docs is explained as

> when you define a bean definition and it is scoped as a singleton, then the Spring IoC container will create exactly one instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single instance will be stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean will result in the cached object being returned.

So in your case, `Set<String> localSet;` is initialized when the IOC container (application, generally) starts up and this same instance is used for different requests until the container shuts down. You can however change the scope of your component. More on scopes [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes).

`@Component`  explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)